# Calculate Volume of $S:= \{(x,y,z) \in \Bbb R^3 \mid z\gt 0, a^2 \lt x^2+y^2+z^2 \lt b^2, z^2 \lt c^2(x^2+y^2) \}$

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-measure, change-of-variable

$0\lt a \lt b$ and $c\gt 0$ and  I want to calculate $\lambda ^3(S)$.

I think I have to use some transformation but I already tried transforming into polar coordinates and it didn't work.
Any tipps on what transformation to use? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll assume that $a$, $b$ and $c$ are positive.
The set $S$ has a cylindrical symmetry around the $z$ axis, so it can be convenient to change the coordinates as
\begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix}
x\\y\\z
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
\rho\cos\theta\\
\rho\sin\theta\\
z
\end{pmatrix},
\end{equation}
with $(\rho,\theta,z)\in(0,+\infty)\times(0,2\pi)\times\mathbb{R}$.
Let $g$ be the transformation from cylindrical to rectangular coordinates: it is easy to see that
\begin{equation}
g^{-1}(S)=\{z>0,a^2<\rho^2+z^2<b^2,z^2<c^2\rho^2\}.
\end{equation}
It is very useful to visualize this set: remembering that $\rho$ and $z$ are positive in $S$, the intersection of $S$ with a plane of constant $\theta$ (for any value of $\theta$) is

[image]

The volume is then
\begin{equation}
\lambda^3(S)=
\int_0^{2\pi}\mathrm{d}\theta\int_U\rho\,\mathrm{d}\lambda'
\end{equation}
where $\lambda'$ is the Lebesgue measure on the plane and
\begin{equation}
U=\{(\rho,z)\in\mathbb{R}^2\colon a^2<\rho^2+z^2< b^2, 0<z<c\rho\}.
\end{equation}
This other integral can be solved resorting again to polar coordinates, this time in $\mathbb{R}^2$.
Considering the coordinate transformation $h$ defined as
\begin{equation}
h
\begin{pmatrix}
r\\\eta
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
r\cos\eta\\
r\sin\eta
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
\rho\\
z
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
for $r\in(0,+\infty)$, $\eta\in(0,2\pi)$; the inequality $z<c\rho$ is equivalent to $\sin\eta<c\cos\eta$ which gives (since $\cos\eta>0$)
\begin{equation}
\eta<\arctan c,
\end{equation}
so
\begin{equation}
h^{-1}(U)=\{(r,\eta)\in(0,+\infty)\times(0,2\pi)\colon a<r<b,0<\eta<\arctan c\},
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
\int_U\rho\,\mathrm{d}\lambda'=
\int_a^b\int_0^{\arctan c} r^2\cos\eta\,\mathrm{d}\eta\,\mathrm{d} r
\end{equation}

Comment: Ah ok so i have to switch coordinates two times. Thanks a lot i didn't think of that.

Comment: Actually I made a mistake, I switched coordinates too soon the second time. I corrected my answer.